# Scrollview doesnt scroll because of weight android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

So i added weightsum and weight to my GUI and it doesnt scroll anymore now.
It worked before i added the weight. I've researched online if there would be a solution but i can't find information anywhere

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:background="#2aa5a5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inside_linear"
            android:weightSum="120">
        </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#D3D3D3"
            android:text="Sorteer op"
            android:id="@+id/sorteer_button"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/maps_button"
            android:background="#D3D3D3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:text="Google Maps"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the dynamic code where which i add the buttons and textview to the inside linearlayout.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dummyNames.length;i++){
            LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
            linearLayoutParams.weight = 20;
            linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linear.setPadding(10,0,0,0);
            linear.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
            TextView restName = new TextView(this);
            restName.setText(dummyNames[i]);
            restName.setTextSize(18);
            Button menuButton = new Button(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(167,100);
            buttonLayoutParams.setMargins(30,0,0,0);
            menuButton.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
            menuButton.setId(i);
            menuButton.setText("menu");
            menuButton.setTextSize(13);
            menuButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedbutton);
            Button infoButton = new Button(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams infoLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(167,100);
            infoLayoutParams.setMargins(30,0,0,0);
            infoButton.setLayoutParams(infoLayoutParams);
            infoButton.setId(i);
            infoButton.setText("info");
            infoButton.setTextSize(13);
            infoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedbutton);
            Button locatieButton = new Button(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams locatieLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(167,100);
            locatieLayoutParams.setMargins(30,0,0,0);
            locatieButton.setLayoutParams(locatieLayoutParams);
            locatieButton.setId(i);
            locatieButton.setText("locatie");
            locatieButton.setTextSize(13);
            locatieButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedbutton);
            Button websiteButton = new Button(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams websiteLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(167,100);
            websiteLayoutParams.setMargins(30,0,0,0);
            websiteButton.setLayoutParams(websiteLayoutParams);
            websiteButton.setId(i);
            websiteButton.setText("website");
            websiteButton.setTextSize(13);
            websiteButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedbutton);

            linear.addView(restName);
            linear.addView(menuButton);
            linear.addView(infoButton);
            linear.addView(locatieButton);
            linear.addView(websiteButton);
           mInsideLinear.addView(linear);
```

Comment: linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); why do you need this??

Comment: can you please post your screenshot of previous output??

Comment: @Jeeva It just showed the linearlayouts and i could scroll between them. I had set a fixed height for them all.. but now when i work with weigth i'm not able to scroll anymore. The weight and weightsum works but the scrolling doesnt

Comment: Using weights in a `LinearLayout` with `wrap_content` doesn't make much sense, and the described behavior isn't surprising. Weights are used to distribute whatever space is available. `wrap_content` just tells the `LinearLayout` shrink as much as it can. Neither of those give a definite measure to either the `LinearLayout` or its children, and without anything to base its height figure on, it just defaults to what you see.

Comment: Ye i get what you mean but i still can't fix it. I have set it to match parent now but it didnt change a thing

Comment: Well, yeah, if it's the same height as the `ScrollView`, there's nothing to scroll. You need to decide what is going to determine the full height of the `LinearLayout`, keeping in mind that it's not going to scroll unless it's taller than the `ScrollView`; a definite height on the `LinearLayout` itself, or definite heights on the child `View`s.